# How to specify hash values in aria2c input file

Tags: download, checksum, aria2

I have a list of files with corresponding SHA256 hash values that I need to download and verify. After looking at the documentation for aria2c, I found that you can specify a hash value for the download so that aria2c can verify the integrity. The problem I'm having is how to specify the hash values within an input file.
My input file is as follows:

```
https://esgf.ceda.ac.uk/thredds/fileServer/esg_cmip6/CMIP6/HighResMIP/CMCC/CMCC-CM2-VHR4/highresSST-future/r1i1p1f1/Amon/hur/gn/v20190725/hur_Amon_CMCC-CM2-VHR4_highresSST-future_r1i1p1f1_gn_201501-201501.nc
  checksum=sha-256=86242dbe5cec36208eb1a47c3bdcad439071f4c954e99e9a1950be6e4f6f3015
https://esgf.ceda.ac.uk/thredds/fileServer/esg_cmip6/CMIP6/HighResMIP/CMCC/CMCC-CM2-VHR4/highresSST-future/r1i1p1f1/Amon/hur/gn/v20190725/hur_Amon_CMCC-CM2-VHR4_highresSST-future_r1i1p1f1_gn_201502-201502.nc
  checksum=sha-256=5ce0a6306156398675d5b7b3ec40207fbe1a5626cb4516e3cfe73b76118ed1f7'
https://esgf.ceda.ac.uk/thredds/fileServer/esg_cmip6/CMIP6/HighResMIP/CMCC/CMCC-CM2-VHR4/highresSST-future/r1i1p1f1/Amon/hur/gn/v20190725/hur_Amon_CMCC-CM2-VHR4_highresSST-future_r1i1p1f1_gn_201503-201503.nc
  checksum=sha-256=db74f6b30acc5691cf11e5b69c943f27856fe1f6e8f252b4061febf2deadd6cb
```

and I invoke aria2c like:

```
aria2c --http-user='' --http-passwd='' -i test.txt
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
Exception caught
Exception: [AbstractOptionHandler.cc:69] errorCode=28 We encountered a problem while processing the option '--checksum'.
  -> [OptionHandlerImpl.cc:395] errorCode=1 Unrecognized checksum
```

I have tried to do download a single file with checksum verification and it works:

```
aria2c --http-user='' --http-passwd='' https://esgf.ceda.ac.uk/thredds/fileServer/esg_cmip6/CMIP6/HighResMIP/CMCC/CMCC-CM2-VHR4/highresSST-future/r1i1p1f1/Amon/hur/gn/v20190725/hur_Amon_CMCC-CM2-VHR4_highresSST-future_r1i1p1f1_gn_201503-201503.nc -V --checksum=sha-256=db74f6b30acc5691cf11e5b69c943f27856fe1f6e8f252b4061febf2deadd6cd
```

Where did I go wrong?

Note: You'll need a username and password to download these files.